# rspec uninitialized constant Event (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

rspecを実行しようとすると以下のエラーが出ます

```
/Users/(user_name)/rails_projects/(project_name)/spec/models/event_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Event (NameError)
```

以下`spec/models/event_spec.rb`です。

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Event do
  descrive '#name' do
    context '空白の時' do
      it 'valid でないこと' do
        event = Event.new(name: '')
        event.valid?
        expect(event.errors[:name]).to be_present
      end
    end
  end
end
```

NoNameErrorと出ていますが、Eventモデルは作成済みです。
`rails_helper.rb`,`spec_helper.rb`共にデフォルトの状態ですが、何か追加で記述する必要があるのでしょうか。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rspec-rails 3系をお使いであることを前提に回答します。

`spec/models/event_spec.rb`の1行目にある
`require 'spec_helper'`を`require 'rails_helper'`とすれば動くと思います。
rspec-rails 3から`spec_helper`の代りに`rails_helper`を`require`することになりました。

参考
https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/v3.4.0/README.md#upgrade-note